# Ошибка при записи данных в БД - can't adapt type 'method'

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql, psycopg2

Добавляю данные в postgresSQl с помощью psycopg2 и выдает такую ошибку can't adapt type 'method', раньше добавлял и все было хорошо, а сейчас немного отрефакторил код и стало бить одну и ту же ошибку.

Comment: код в студию...

Comment: большой очень код, перебрал по символам

Comment: curs.execute('''
INSERT INTO flats (link, reference, price, title, description, date, area, square, city, rooms, micro) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON CONFLICT (link) DO UPDATE
SET
link = EXCLUDED.link,
reference = EXCLUDED.reference,
price = EXCLUDED.price,
title = EXCLUDED.title,
description = EXCLUDED.description,
date = EXCLUDED.date,
area = EXCLUDED.area,
square = EXCLUDED.square,
city = EXCLUDED.city,
rooms = EXCLUDED.rooms,
micro = EXCLUDED.micro
''', тут я вставлял все данные)